# Speed up a simple edge connecting algorithm

Tags: python, performance, algorithm, graph, cython

I have a list of edges and a similar list of links (linking edges) telling which edges to connect (how to order them). Connected edges form polygons and there can be many disconnected polygons (ordering of which doesn't matter). For example:

```
edges = [((2, 1), (3, 1)), ((4, 1), (6, 1)), ((6, 4), (4, 4)), ((3, 6), (2, 6))]
links = [((2, 6), (2, 1)), ((3, 1), (3, 6)), ((4, 4), (4, 1)), ((6, 1), (6, 4))]
```

We would connect the edge `((2, 1), (3, 1))` with the edge `((3, 6), (2, 6))` because the linking edge `((3, 1), (3, 6))` is in `links`, etc. The result would be ordering of `edges` as:

```
[((2, 1), (3, 1)), ((3, 6), (2, 6)), ((4, 1), (6, 1)), ((6, 4), (4, 4))]
```

where `((2, 1), (3, 1)), ((3, 6), (2, 6))` forms a polygon and `((4, 1), (6, 1)), ((6, 4), (4, 4))` another one.

So the idea is to check if `(edge[i][1], edge[j][0])` is in `links`, for all `i!=j`. If true, then connect the `edge[i]` with `edge[j]` by putting the latter after the former, and repeat with `(edge[j][1], edge[k][0])` etc.

I use the following function to do it:

```
def connect_edges(edges, links):
    edges = dict(edges)
    links = dict(links)      
    seen = set()
    edges_connected = []
    for e in edges.items():
        while e not in seen:
            seen.add(e)
            edges_connected.append(e)
            e = (links[e[1]], edges[links[e[1]]])
    return edges_connected
```

It is quite fast, but for a very large number of edges (e.g. 1 million) it takes almost 20 seconds on my old laptop. Is there a way to speed it up? I think it is more or less optimal and maybe could be cynthonized for a gain in speed, but the problem is that it is very pythonic (having lists of tuples, dictionaries, sets) and I don't know if it will work (my knowledge of cython is very limited). Simply cythonizing without declaring types gives minuscule speed-up.

Comment: You're talking about graphs, so are `edges` really vertices and are `links` actually edges?  Are `links` directed? Can they only connect in one direction? When you write "polygon", do you mean "polyline"? Polygons should be rings, with the last vertex being the first one.

Comment: `edges` and `links` are both lists of edges (horizontal edges and vertical edges of a rectilinear polygon, respectively). For example, in ((2, 1), (3, 1)) --  ((3, 6), (2, 6)), the edges ((2, 1), (3, 1))  and ((3, 6), (2, 6)) are horizontal edges from`edges` and the  ((3, 1), (3, 6)) is a vertical edge from `links`.  If it is confusing, you indeed can think of elements of `edges`as nodes and the elements of `links` as edges connecting the nodes of a graph.

Comment: Technically they form polylines as you say, but later on I add the first vertex to the end to close it (I didn't show it here in order to make the code simpler). And yes, they are directed in the sense that they form a polygon if the vertices are connected in the given order e.g. (2, 1) -- (3, 1) --  (3, 6) -- (2, 6) -- (2,1). Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Just curious : why do you need it? Don't you need more information, e.g. each polyline grouped together instead of being concatenated into a single list, without separator? Aren't there multiple, possible orderings?

Answer (score 1):

Just a collection of thoughts...

## Terminology

Since you're talking about graphs, it might help the readers if you talk about nodes (your `edges`) and edges (your `links`).

Your graph is directed, and as far as I can tell, you're looking for the ["strongly connected components"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_connected_component).

## Use simpler objects

Lists of pairs of pairs aren't very readable IMHO. When showing examples, you can replace them with lists of strings:

```
edges = ['AB', 'CD', 'EF', 'GH']
links = ['HA', 'BG', 'FC', 'DE']
```

Python strings are basically tuples of characters, so you don't have to change much in your code. The above example is isomorphic to yours and is much more concise.

## KeyError

When calling `edges[links[e[1]]`, you're hoping there won't be any `KeyError`. Your example would fail with :

```
edges = ['AB', 'CD', 'EF', 'GH']
links = ['HA', 'BG', 'FC']
```

## Links between multiple edges

What happens in the case of link connecting more than 2 edges, for example

```
edges = ['AB', 'GH', 'AC']
links = ['HA']
```

? Your current algorithm doesn't seem to take it into account. A `defaultdict(list)` might help, for example to keep a list of nodes beginning with `A` and another list for nodes finishing with `H`.

## Output format

If you only sort the edges, without grouping them in connected components, you're losing information which you have to recover later. You could return a list of sets of edges instead of a flat list of edges.

```
[{'AB', 'GH'}, {'CD', 'EF'}]
```

## networkx

If you work with graph theory in Python, you should take a look at [`networkx`](https://networkx.github.io/). It's fast, easy to use and offers many algorithms. All you need to do is to preprocess your data and feed it to a `nx.DiGraph`.

Your example could become:

```
import networkx as nx
from collections import defaultdict
import matplotlib

edges = ['AB', 'CD', 'EF', 'GH']
links = ['HA', 'BG', 'FC', 'DE']

G = nx.DiGraph()

from_dict = defaultdict(list)
to_dict = defaultdict(list)

for edge in edges:
    node = ''.join(edge)
    G.add_node(node)
    to_dict[node[0]].append(node)
    from_dict[node[1]].append(node)

for link in links:
    for node1 in from_dict[link[0]]:
        for node2 in to_dict[link[1]]:
            G.add_edge(node1, node2)

list(nx.strongly_connected_components(G))
# [{'AB', 'GH'}, {'CD', 'EF'}]
nx.draw(G, with_labels = True)
```

It displays:

[image]

You get more information, it's more robust, you get diagrams if you want, it can handle more complex cases and (who knows?) it might be faster than your solution for large datasets.